# Object giving "must be a pointer-to-class type" when using -> and "must be a class type" when using

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Working on a graph class for a data structures class and I am running into an issue with an edge object on the lines:

```
        myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back.n1 = myGraph.nodes[a];
        myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back->n2 = myGraph.nodes[b];
        myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back.cost = c;
```

If I try to operate on the object as if it is a pointer it tells me it must be a pointer-to-class type (C2227) and if I try to operate on it as a class type it tells me it must be a class type (C2228)

I have tried everything I know how to do and reached out to all my peers on this issue (my professor is unable to be reached). I am not aware of a third type or way to reference the members.

Any issues should be contained to the main.cpp file I know the lab11 code works fine.

They are all pointers and so they should be referenced with the -> operator but they simply aren't.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "lab11.cpp";

using namespace std;

int main() {

}

Graph writeGraph(string filename) {
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(filename);

    int numberofnodes;

    myfile >> numberofnodes;
    Graph myGraph;



    for (int i = 0; i < numberofnodes; i++) {
        myGraph.nodes.push_back(new Node(i));
    }

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

    while (myfile >> a) {
        if (a == -1) {
            break;
        }
        myfile >> b >> c;
        Edge *newEdge();

        Node * temp = myGraph.nodes[a];

        myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.push_back(new Edge());
        myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back.n1 = myGraph.nodes[a];
        myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back->n2 = myGraph.nodes[b];
        myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back.cost = c;

    }
}
```

lab11.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class Node;

class Edge {
public:
    Edge() { n1 = 0; n2 = 0; inspanningtree = false; }
    Node * n1;
    Node * n2;
    int cost;

    bool inspanningtree;
};

class Node {
public:
    Node(int nodeNumber)
    {
        this->nodeNumber = nodeNumber;
        lastnum = -1;
    }
    int nodeNumber;
    vector<Edge *> edges;
    int lastnum;
};

class Graph {
public:
    vector<Node *> nodes;
    vector<Edge *> edges;
};

/*
void shellsortEdge( vector<Edge *> & a )
{
    for( int gap = a.size( ) / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2 )
        for( int i = gap; i < a.size( ); ++i )
        {
            Edge * tmp = std::move( a[ i ] );
            int j = i;

            for( ; j >= gap && *tmp < *(a[ j - gap ]); j -= gap )
                a[ j ] = std::move( a[ j - gap ] );
            a[ j ] = std::move( tmp );
        }
}*/







int glastnum = 0;
bool find(Node * current, Node * tofind, Node * from)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < current->edges.size(); i++) {


        if (current->edges[i]->inspanningtree) {
            if (current->edges[i]->n1 != from  && current != current->edges[i]->n1)//prob
            {
                if (current->edges[i]->n1->lastnum == glastnum) {
                    return true;
                }
                current->edges[i]->n1->lastnum = glastnum;
                bool b = find(current->edges[i]->n1, tofind, current);
                if (b == true)
                return true;

            }
            if (current->edges[i]->n2 != from && current != current->edges[i]->n2)//prob
            {
                if (current->edges[i]->n2->lastnum == glastnum) {
                    return true;
                }
                current->edges[i]->n2->lastnum = glastnum;
                bool b = find(current->edges[i]->n2, tofind, current);
                if (b == true)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


bool doesAddingThisMakeACycle(Graph & g, Edge * toBeAdded)
{
    toBeAdded->inspanningtree = true;
    glastnum++;

    Node * n1 = toBeAdded->n1;
    Node * n2 = toBeAdded->n2;

    bool b = find(n1, n1, n1);
    if (b) {
        toBeAdded->inspanningtree = false;
        return true;
    }

    glastnum++;

    b = find(n2, n2, n2);
    if (b) {
        toBeAdded->inspanningtree = false;
        return true;
    }

    toBeAdded->inspanningtree = false;

    return false;
}
```

I hate to come here for homework help because I know how much it is frowned upon but I am simply out of other options I will happily delete this if it isn't appropriate

Comment: remove `Edge *newEdge();`

Comment: `edges.back.n1` should be `edges.back()->n1`, similarly for `cost` and `n2` just after.

Comment: @M.M `back` is a function in `std::vector`, not a member variable. Should be `edges.back()->n1`.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers fixed!

Comment: Thank you! wow I feel Dumb! I can't believe I couldn't get that!

Comment: @BlaineShelton We've all been there. Welcome to the club.

Answer (score 1):

`back` is a member function of `std::vector`. You are missing the function call.

```
myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back()->n1 = myGraph.nodes[a];
myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back()->n2 = myGraph.nodes[b];
myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back()->cost = c;
```

Alternatively,

```
Edge* edge = myGraph.nodes[a]->edges.back();
edge->n1 = myGraph.nodes[a];
edge->n2 = myGraph.nodes[b];
edge->cost = c;
```